# WPF Mousebutton Command Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts, commandbinding

is there a way to bind an command to an mousebutton similar how you would bind to an keyboard button?

I'm doing this with my Keyboard Command:

```
 Application.Current.MainWindow.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(this.NavigateForward, Key.Y, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

and I would like to do something like this

```
 Application.Current.MainWindow.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(this.NavigateForward, MouseButtons.XButton1)); //Not possible?
```

Comment: you can do it for left/right/middle button single/double click and wheel click  but not for XButton

Comment: How would I do it with left/right for example?

Comment: use `MouseBinding` like so `InputBindings.Add(new MouseBinding(this.NavigateForward, new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick)))`

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to try the MvvMlight Toolkit library, it exposes the `EventToCommand` action, with which any action may be related to a command, in a clean way. Also it works for Sliverlight, Windows Phone, and Windows Store Applications.

- [In CodePlex](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)
- [Mvvm Light Site](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)